# Excel - Pick out a string from a range of strings

Tags: excel, lookup

I have 2 columns of data and I need to use one to pull out one element of the other.

1. I have a list of addresses, where the entire address is in one cell.  There is no standard format or delimiter. I need to pull out the city only into a separate cell.
2. I also have a list of cities that can be used as a lookup.

What I need the formula to do is look in the address cell and pull out the city, where the city is within my list in point 2.

As an example  here is the first 4 rows of addresses;

```
42493 CLONSILLA ROAD DUBLIN 15 DUBLIN
2 Glenavey Rd Company Antrim Antrim Ireland
Tesco Wexford Road Arklow n a Wicklow Ireland
GROVE SERVICE STATION BAYLOUGH ATHLONE WESTMEATH
```

And an extract of the towns list;

```
Duagh
Dualla
Dublin
Duhallow
Duleek
```

For row 1, the formula needs to look through the towns and bring back Dublin.
Any ideas on this one?  I'm a bit lost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to use an [Array Formula](http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/array-formulas.html)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$1:$D$5,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND(LOWER($D$1:$D$5),LOWER(A2))),-1,1)*ROW($D$1:$D$5))-ROW($D$1)+1),"")
```

would work in the following example, you willl need to use Ctrl + Shift + Enter to confirm the formula as opposed to just Enter [image: I made]

The formula is a bit involved, I've tried to break it down below:

- $D1:$D$5 - represents the cities you want to find
- LOWER is used to ignore uppercase v lowercase
- The FIND formula searches the text in column A for any of D1:D5,
  which errors for those not found
- ISERROR returns TRUE if a city isn't found and FALSE otherwise
- IF converts the TRUEs (not founds) to -1 and the FALSE (found) to 1
- This is then multiplied by the ROW number, and MAX selects the
  maximum number, which will be the row number of the found city
- INDEX then returns the name of the city based on the row number it
  receives
- In the case where no match is found IFERROR returns a blank

Comment: Genius!  thank you very much, i'd have never got to there!